# Vue.js Component Template Type

Tags: laravel, vue.js, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

At my company, for templates for Vue.js, we write components in separate Blade files. The problem I have is that HTML code is not highlighted in those files. Whole HTML code is written inside `script` tags which has the syntax:

`<script type="x/templates" id="nameOfComponent">`.

By deleting the type attribute, highlighting starts working correctly. I have searched a little bit and found that there are different types, but I have never seen one like the one above (the closest one I saw is `text/x-template` and highlighting works with it). Now, as I am not allowed to change these kinds of things, I have a couple of questions (also, I have to mention I'm new to JavaScript and PHP):

- If this is not predefined type, are user-defined types supported?
- If so, is there any extension for VS code which would highlight HTML part of the code?
- If user-defined types are not the right solution, which one would be the best solution for me?

Comment: Yeah, that MIME type looks invalid. Seems like a developer‘s got it wrong, stuck with that convention, which sucks if you’re not allowed to change it now. I’m also not sure what advantage putting templates in script tags like this has over say, single-file components.

Comment: When you say 'single-file' you mean putting together JavaScript and HTML code into same file? Is that the right way of using Vue? The way which lets you get the most of it?

Comment: You can create **.vue** files that contain both the template mark-up and JavaScript for a Vue component: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: I get it now. As I said, here we separate template from JS, and even it's maybe not the best way, I have already get used to it. I'm gonna suggest changing MIME type, finally it's just one _find/replace_ through whole project, nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

try:

https://github.com/vuejs/vetur

Pretty sure it should support vue template syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I have downloaded it, but didn't help in my case. Thanks again!